# Specifying the List Title in an Ebay Scrape

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

im new with programming and computers in general. ive got a little
basic knowledge and im trying to do an ebay scraper ive been working on.

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

titles = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'vip'})
titles = str(titles)
print(titles)
```

this code returns a list like so:

```
[
<a class="vip" href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/HAYNES-HONDA-CIVIC-DEL-SOL-1991-1995-REPAIR-MANUAL-/121848077988?hash=item1c5eb61ea4:g:M5gAAOSwf-VWahyW&amp;vxp=mtr" title="Click this link to access HAYNES HONDA CIVIC DEL SOL 1991-1995 REPAIR MANUAL">HAYNES HONDA CIVIC DEL SOL 1991-1995 REPAIR MANUAL</a>, 

<a class="vip" href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/1992-1995-HONDA-CIVIC-DEL-SOL-FUSE-BOX-/320502127733?hash=item4a9f6a5c75:m:mHAEk2bNyOI4W8-qUiEnGWw&amp;vxp=mtr" title="Click this link to access 1992 - 1995 HONDA CIVIC/DEL SOL FUSE BOX">1992 - 1995 HONDA CIVIC/DEL SOL FUSE BOX</a>, 

<a class="vip" href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/HAYNES-HONDA-CIVIC-DEL-SOL-1991-1995-REPAIR-MANUAL-/111847121189?hash=item1a0a9ba125:g:M5gAAOSwf-VWahyW&amp;vxp=mtr" title="Click this link to access HAYNES HONDA CIVIC DEL SOL 1991-1995 REPAIR MANUAL">HAYNES HONDA CIVIC DEL SOL 1991-1995 REPAIR MANUAL</a>,

<a class="vip" href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/1996-2000-HONDA-CIVIC-DEL-SOL-all-models-repair-manual-/401035736130?hash=item5d5f97b442:g:UjAAAOSwxN5WXm-M&amp;vxp=mtr" title="Click this link to access 1996-2000 HONDA CIVIC &amp; DEL SOL - all models - repair manual">1996-2000 HONDA CIVIC &amp; DEL SOL - all models - repair manual</a>, 

<a class="vip" href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/Haynes-42024-1992-1995-Honda-Civic-and-del-sol-repair-manual-/321920364888?hash=item4af3f2f158:g:9GoAAOSwLzdWRog0&amp;vxp=mtr" title="Click this link to access Haynes 42024 1992-1995 Honda Civic and del sol repair manual.">Haynes 42024 1992-1995 Honda Civic and del sol repair manual.</a>, 

<a class="vip" href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/1988-2000-honda-acura-civic-integra-del-sol-pvc-valve-17130-pm6-003-oem-a137-/141782449307?hash=item2102e47c9b:g:iB8AAOSw0HVWAg5x&amp;vxp=mtr" title="Click this link to access 1988-2000 honda acura civic integra del sol pvc valve 17130-pm6-003 oem a137">1988-2000 honda acura civic integra del sol pvc valve 17130-pm6-003 oem a137</a>, 

<a class="vip" href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/88-2000-Honda-Civic-5-Speed-Manual-Shift-Knob-OEM-CRX-EF-EG-Si-Del-Sol-89-96-/262152990857?hash=item3d09893089:g:1x4AAOSwlV9WT7fj&amp;vxp=mtr" title="Click this link to access 88 - 2000 Honda Civic 5 Speed Manual Shift Knob OEM CRX EF EG Si Del Sol 89 96">88 - 2000 Honda Civic 5 Speed Manual Shift Knob OEM CRX EF EG Si Del Sol 89 96</a>, 

<a class="vip" href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/1988-2000-Honda-Civic-CRX-EF-SI-DX-HF-Del-Sol-Manual-Shift-Knob-OEM-88-91-/281859356536?hash=item41a0207778:g:XTAAAOSwMmBVj5mr&amp;vxp=mtr" title="Click this link to access 1988-2000 Honda Civic CRX EF SI DX HF Del Sol Manual Shift Knob OEM 88-91">1988-2000 Honda Civic CRX EF SI DX HF Del Sol Manual Shift Knob OEM 88-91</a>, 

<a class="vip" href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/Chilton-Repair-Manual-Honda-Civic-Del-Sol-1996-00-/262123397570?hash=item3d07c5a1c2:g:decAAOSwA4dWNs07&amp;vxp=mtr" title="Click this link to access Chilton Repair Manual Honda Civic &amp; Del Sol, 1996-00">Chilton Repair Manual Honda Civic &amp; Del Sol, 1996-00</a>
]
```

what i would like to do at this point, is specifically receive JUST the title of the listing. This is so i can take count up the frequency of each word in my list set.

expected output:

```
[
'1992 - 1995 HONDA CIVIC/DEL SOL FUSE BOX',
'Chilton Repair Manual Honda Civic &amp; Del Sol, 1996-00',
'ETC'
]
```

if you'll notice, there are two places in each line that display the title. first at

```
"title=Click this link to access..."
```

and again right after it, and goes to the end of the line. 
i tried using string.split() and other variants, but i cant figure out how to use it in such a way that will specify just the words within the title. i keep getting different jumbles of words, one letter per line, or just the whole entire list item, etc etc.

anybody know a good method?

Comment: I would recommend joining the eBay developers program and using their API.  It is much better and free.  https://go.developer.ebay.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.get_text()` for every element found:

```
[a.get_text() for a in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'vip'})]
```

Comment: @indianhearts the provided code would loop over the `a` elements with `class="vip"` and get the text of every element found. What is the problem? Thanks.